# Custom view border colour using ColorWithPatternImage is generating error in iOS 6.1?

Tags: ios, uicolor

```
    myView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    myView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:@"color.png"];
```

The second line is giving error Implicit conversion of OBjective-C pointer type 'UIColor' to pointer type 'CGColorRef' requires a bridged cast
.

What is this error and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The line should be:

```
myView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:@"color.png"] CGColor];
```

Because you have a `UIColor` but the layer, as described by the error, requires a `CGColorRef`.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString _tiledPatternColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2aa7b8'

Comment: This is error, Crash app, there is one warning on this line. it says incomplete pointer type sending nsstring to parameter of type uiimage

Comment: myView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"color.png"]] CGColor];

Comment: I did this, it works fine now :)     myView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"color.png"]] CGColor];